# Why isn't EF 4 updating list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am running into a problem where a list object is selected, edited, and then redirected back to the list, but the object is not showing that it has been updated on the list. If the edited object's details view is selected, the editing to the object has been saved. I need the list to update the changes that have been made.

This is the method that the generates the list for the "Index" view:

```
public static List<MortgageCancellation> DealerSorting(string id,string dealerId)
    {
        var d = from u in db.MortgageCancellations
                where u.DealerID == dealerId
                select u;
        switch (id)
        {
            case "DealID":
                return d.OrderBy(u => u.DealID).ToList();
            case "PrimaryFirstName":
                return d.OrderBy(u => u.PrimaryFirstName).ToList();
            case "PrimaryLastName":
                return d.OrderBy(u => u.PrimaryLastName).ToList();
            case "DateOfApplication":
                return d.OrderBy(u => u.DateOfApplication).ToList();
            case "ProfileStatus":
                return d.OrderBy(u => u.ProfileStatus).ToList();
            case "CurrentStep":
                return d.OrderByDescending(u => u.CurrentStep).ToList();
            case "LastUpdated":
                return d.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastUpdated).ToList();
            default:
                return d.ToList();
        }
    }
```

This is where the editing takes place, which you can see saves the changes:

```
public ActionResult Edit(MortgageCancellation mortgagecancellation)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                mortgagecancellation.DateOfApplication = (DateTime?)Session["appDate"];
                Session.Remove("appDate");
                mortgagecancellation.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                db.Entry(mortgagecancellation).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(mortgagecancellation);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SupportEmail se = new SupportEmail(error, ex);
            SupportEmail.SendSupportEmail(se);
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why the "Index" view isn't showing the changes that have been made as this is the only method called from the "Index" view:

```
return View(MortgageCancellation.OfficeSorting(id));
```

One more thing, the list *eventually* shows the changes, but I need the list show the changes *immediately*.

This is where the db is initialized:

```
private static MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
```

Comment: little off topic, but what is this `SupportEmail` object, and why isn't the syntax `se.Send()` rather than calling a static method?

Comment: Where is DealerSorting called? and where are you defining 'db'?

Comment: Could you provide code that initialize db Context.

Comment: @Mark That method has a couple of other methods encapsulated.

Comment: @devdigital The DealerSorting() is called from the "Index" view.

Comment: @AlexT Both the DealerSorting() and DbContext are located on the same model.

Comment: I'd highly recommend not using a static db context - you'll end up with major concurrency issues with multiple people hitting the site (and your current issue could be a side-effect of this).  The DbContext object is pretty lightweight and should in instantiated and disposed per request, not a single global one for the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace

```
private static MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
```

with a

```
using(var db = new MyDBContext())
{
    ...code..
}
```

for each action.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to try that until today, and it did do the trick! Thanks.